# How do I get the total number of SSTables with nodetool?

Tags: cassandra

I am referencing following documentation: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsTablestats.html#Examples

I would like to get the total number of SSTables. For that I tried using the `nodetool tablestats` command and adding up all the values of the `SSTable count` field of the table objects.

I noticed, that this field is not present in the yaml format, only in the plain text format. Is there another way to get this number?

In Addition, I wanted to ask if the number of active SSTables is equal to the number of open files of the cassandra process?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! A friendly note that you should avoid multiple questions in a single post. Please only ask one question in each post and create multiple posts if you need to ask multiple questions. For reference, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371617/4269535. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can write a script to loop through the output of `nodetool tablestats` to add up all the SSTable counts to get the total. There isn't a command that would give you a total because that statistic is not tracked by Cassandra.

Also, we only use YAMLs for configuration files, not command outputs. Cheers!

Comment: Ok thats what I was doing anyway. I was just wondering whether I could work with the "-F yaml" parameter to make handling in the script easier, but parsing it out of the plain-text-output works too.

Answer (score 2):

thank you for the question!

`nodetool tablestats` does provide an option (`-F / --format`) to convert/display the output in `yaml` or `json` format.

With an utility like `jq`, one could easily get the desired value.

For example, consider the following keyspace/table combination `test.udt_test` and if the output of `nodetool tablestats --format json -- test.udt_test` is as follows,

```
{
  "test" : {
    "read_latency_ms" : "NaN",
    "write_count" : 0,
    "pending_flushes" : 0,
    "tables" : {
      "udt_test" : {
        "bloom_filter_space_used" : "56",
        "bytes_repaired" : 0,
        "compacted_partition_maximum_bytes" : 50,
        "index_summary_off_heap_memory_used" : "0",
        "off_heap_memory_used_total" : "56",
        "local_read_latency_ms" : "NaN",
        "local_write_latency_ms" : "NaN",
        "local_read_count" : 0,
        "space_used_live" : "15974",
        "bloom_filter_false_positives" : 0,
        "compression_metadata_off_heap_memory_used" : "24",
        "average_tombstones_per_slice_last_five_minutes" : "NaN",
        "average_live_cells_per_slice_last_five_minutes" : "NaN",
        "number_of_partitions_estimate" : 9,
        "dropped_mutations" : "0",
        "memtable_switch_count" : 2,
        "compacted_partition_minimum_bytes" : 30,
        "percent_repaired" : 0.0,
        "sstables_in_each_level" : [ ],
        "bloom_filter_false_ratio" : "0.00000",
        "bloom_filter_off_heap_memory_used" : "32",
        "sstable_compression_ratio" : 0.5630841121495327,
        "memtable_off_heap_memory_used" : "0",
        "local_write_count" : 0,
        "space_used_total" : "15974",
        "bytes_unrepaired" : 428,
        "memtable_cell_count" : 0,
        "space_used_by_snapshots_total" : "0",
        "memtable_data_size" : "0",
        "maximum_tombstones_per_slice_last_five_minutes" : 0,
        "maximum_live_cells_per_slice_last_five_minutes" : 0,
        "pending_flushes" : 0,
        "bytes_pending_repair" : 0,
        "compacted_partition_mean_bytes" : 38
      }
    },
    "write_latency_ms" : "NaN",
    "read_count" : 0,
    "read_latency" : "NaN"
  },
  "total_number_of_tables" : 159
}
```

I could easily fetch just the value for `total_number_of_tables` using the following command,

```
nodetool tablestats --format json -- test.udt_test | jq '.total_number_of_tables'

159
```

which you could apply it in your scripting logic. I hope that helps!

p/s: One could also test the `jq` functionality without actually installing it via web tools such as https://www.devtoolsdaily.com/jq_playground/

Comment: Thanks but perhaps I was to unclear in my question. I know those functionalities already, my problem is, that the tablesstats output lacks a certain metric when switching the format. 
In the plain text output there is a field called "SSTables count" but in yaml or json format it is nowhere to be found.